# Plotly: How to change the trace order, or switch the sides of the axes in plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to get the line to display over the bar. It seems that whatever trace has `secondary_y=True` will be drawn on top of the one where `secondary_y=False`.

That's fine, but for this particular data set, the bar axis should be on the right, because otherwise this graph is confusing. The line is the one that is in the 1-3 range, and the bar is the one that is in the 0-35k range.

In other words, it should look just like this, but with y-axes switched. Is there some way to switch the axes, or control the order in which it draws the traces, so that I can force the line to be on top of the bars?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode,  plot
init_notebook_mode()

rdf = pd.read_csv('us_covid_data_latest.csv', dtype={'fips':str})
incidence = pd.pivot_table(rdf, values='cases', index = 'date', aggfunc=np.sum)
incidence['actual_inc'] = incidence['cases'].diff()

def tail_plot_plotly(tail):

    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
            x= incidence['date'].tail(tail),
            y= incidence['actual_inc'].tail(tail)
            ),
        secondary_y = False
        ) 


    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x= incidence['date'].tail(tail),
            y= incidence['R_t'].tail(tail)
            ),
        secondary_y = True
        )

    plot(fig)

tail_plot_plotly(50)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not easy providing a complete solution without a sample of your dataset, but I still think I've figured it out. I'm in a bit of a hurry right now, so I'll make it short:

Bars are big numbers, lines are small numbers. Out of the box, a `fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])` would provide this:

[image]

**`Line trace on top = Good. Bar numbers to the left = Bad.`**

Changing the order of which yoy apply the different traces to the figure won't help. But you can freely specify on which side of the plot you'd like your primary and secondary y axis to appear like this:

```
fig.update_layout(dict(yaxis2={'anchor': 'x', 'overlaying': 'y', 'side': 'left'},
                  yaxis={'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'side':'right'}))
```

Add that to the mix, and you'll get:

[image]

**`Line trace on top = Good. Bar numbers to the right = Good.`**

**Complete code with a data sample:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# set figure twith multiple y axes
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# blue line with numbers from 1 to 3
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               y=[1.5, 1.0, 1.3, 2.7, 1.8, 2.9]),secondary_y=True)

# red bars with big numbers
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           y=[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 100000, 20000, 250000]))

# update layout to put axes and values in the desired positions
fig.update_layout(dict(yaxis2={'anchor': 'x', 'overlaying': 'y', 'side': 'left'},
                  yaxis={'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'side':'right'}))

fig.show()
```

Comment: I will try that next time I get a moment. I think that should work.

Comment: @vestland is it possible to turn off the y1-axis grid? I applied this solution, which works for the traces. However, I want the grid to now show only for the y2-axis, and not the y1-axis.

Comment: @EliTurasky It's possible through `fig.update_layout(yaxis1 = dict(showgrid=False))`. Optionally `fig.update_layout(yaxis2 = dict(showgrid=False))` regarding which one you'd like to display or not.

Comment: I was doing yaxis1_showgrid. The command though is yaxis_showgrid. Thanks