# Plotly: How to control which trace is in front for double y-axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a double y-axis plot that looks like this:

[image]

In this example, the bars are on the secondary y-axis. However, I want the line to be in front of the bars. I thought doing `yaxis2=dict(overlaying='y1')` would solve the issue, but nothing different occurred. The only hackish solution I have come up with so far is to turn the opacity down on the bars so you can actually see the line. Surely though there is a way to fix this that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

The trace on the secondary y-axis will appear on top. No matter if its a `go.Scatter()` trace or a `go.Bar()` trace

#### Details:

The `overlaying` attribute only applies to cases with more than two y-axes, like [here](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/):

[image]

From [the docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-overlaying) you can see that:

> overlaying Parent: layout.xaxis Type: enumerated , one of ( "free" |
> "/^x([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)?$/" | "/^y([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)?$/" ) If set a
> same-letter axis id, this axis is overlaid on top of the corresponding
> same-letter axis, with traces and axes visible for both axes. If
> "False", this axis does not overlay any same-letter axes. In this
> case, for axes with overlapping domains only the highest-numbered axis
> will be visible.

So, how about your case?
Generally, traces are displayed in the order that they are added to the `fig`. But not when it comes to a figure with two y-axes. It seems you will have to switch with trace you're displaying on the primary axis. The first snippet produces a figure with bars on the primary axis. The second snippet producds a figure with bars on the secondary axis. This also determines which trace is shown on top.

#### Code 1:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[40, 50, 60], name="yaxis data"),
    secondary_y=True,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[45, 50, 45], name="yaxis2 data"),
    secondary_y=False,
)
```

fig.show()

#### Plot 1:

[image]

#### Code 2:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[40, 50, 60], name="yaxis data"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[45, 50, 45], name="yaxis2 data"),
    secondary_y=True,
)


fig.show()
```

#### Plot 2:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. That’s frustrating as most people look at the primary y-axis for the main info.

Comment: @EliTurasky Aha. Well, my suggestion answers your question. But we don't need to stop there. Because you *can* determine which side displays the primary axis. Take a look at [Plotly: How to change the trace order, or switch the sides of the axes in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402079/plotly-how-to-change-the-trace-order-or-switch-the-sides-of-the-axes-in-plotly/61408543#61408543) That question is closely related, but not a duplicate. And I realize now that *that* is perhaps exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @EliTurasky Let's talk more details in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222990/room-for-vestland-and-eli-turasky)